# How to select rows not present in another table with 2 columns comparison?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have the following tables:

```
T1                    T2                Desired result
    CA   CB             CA    CC               CA   CB
     1    2              1     3                1    4
     1    4              1     2                2    1
     1    3              1     5                2    3 
     2    1              2     4
     2    3
     3    6
     3    1
     4    ...
```

I need to make a join between T1 and T2 (using column CA) and return only those rows which the values in CB do not exists in T2.CC

A simple way to achieve that is using the following query:

```
    SELECT T1.* FROM T1 INNER JOIN T2 ON t1.CA = t2.CA AND 
    t1.CB NOT IN (SELECT CC FROM T2 WHERE T2.CA = T1.CA)
```

I think the previous query is not very efficient. For that reason I am looking for something better

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, a more efficient means of achieving this sort of result is finding records which *fail* a simpler join condition. Those can be found by doing an outer join and checking for null, as follows:

```
select t1.ca, t1.cb
from t1 left outer join t2 on t1.ca=t2.ca and t1.cb=t2.cc
where t2.ca is null;
```

Comment: I forgot something important @vladimir, Table1 has many other rows. In that case this query returns all the other rows. I did update the example in the question

Comment: select t1ca, t1cb
from (select DISTINCT t1.ca t1ca, t1.cb t1cb from t1 join t2 on t1.ca=t2.ca) left outer join t2 on t1ca=t2.ca and t1cb=t2.cc
where t2.ca is null
;

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want `not exists`:

```
select t1.*
from t1
where not exists (select 1
                  from t2
                  where t2.ca = t1.ca and t2.cb = t1.cb
                 );
```

For performance, you want an index on `t2(ca, cb)`.